# Court order to obtain US death certificate

Tags: united-states, united-kingdom, injunctions, adoption

My father was born in England and adopted as a young child. He never knew who his real parents were. I have recently found out who his mother and father were using DNA tests. I have obtained his original birth certificate from the UK Records Office.

His mother was in the army (ATS) and later emigrated to Tucson, Arizona where she died. I would like to obtain her UK military records. To do this I need her death certificate. The Pima, Arizona records office will only give copies of death certificates to descendants. I applied as her grandchild and sent them birth certificates for myself, my father and his mother along with my father's adoption certificate.

They said the relationship was not proven because his adoption certificate is a "sealed record" that they treat as his birth record and it does not mention his birth mother. They said the only way they could give me the death certificate was if I obtained a court order:

"Any court order as long as it is a certified court order and in a language we can read, or have it translated. In other words a court order from England will work as long as it is certified that Vital Records can issue a death certificate to you."

I have searched online and think I need to get an injunction.

Does anyone have any information on how I could get a court order as described from a UK court?

Thank you

Comment: For clarification: His original birth certificate lists this person as his mother, correct? But his name changed when adopted, so your birth certificate lists a different name as your father (his name after he was adopted), correct? So your problem is completing the link that your father "Adoptedguy Jones" is the same person as "Newbornbaby Smith," whose birth mother you are investigating, correct?

Comment: Yes his original birth certificate is John Doe, mother Miss Jane Doe. His adoption certificate has the names of his adoptive parents, Mr and Mrs Smith, and his name is given as John Doe Smith. The Arizona records office say his adoption certificate is his birth record and it doesn't say his mother is Jane Doe. I know that she is his mother from the DNA test results.

Comment: I got an answer on the Legal Beagles site:
https://legalbeagles.info/forums/forum/legalbeagles-consumer-forums/welcome-forum/1558363-court-order-to-obtain-us-death-certificate